# Changing og:title of self hosted objects

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-stream-story, publish-actions, custom-stories

I'm currently working on a unity project and trying to implement custom stories in the same. I created a self hosted object. I want my og:title to change from  unity code e.g. I want to have multiple titles as I cleared level one, I clear level two etc. Just not able to do it. Is it possible to do so?? I always get the og:title as declared in the meta property of the html page of that object. Please help.

Comment: I dont think you can have multiple og tags. are u using simple Html or any technology

Comment: Using HTML. Og tags can not be multiple thats true. But can we update the og title??

Comment: may be you can update the tag by javascript after the page is loaded. But only tags are fetched by facebook servers before the page can load. So no use. Can you try to create multiple pages were you can redirect to the another page.

Comment: You mean that I create a page for every object. Actually I have a large number of levels in my game. So its not feasible to have such a large number of pages. :(